# What is the difference between an array and collection in JavaScript and when should I choose one over the other?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom, collections

I'm currently reading a book called "JavaScript and jQuery Interactive Front End Web Developement" by Jon Duckett. In the chapter on DOM, it mentions that

> NodeLists look like arrays and are numbered like arrays, but they are
>   not actually arrays. they are a type of object called a collection.

My question is, what is the difference between an array and collection in JavaScript and when should I choose one over the other?

Comment: They don't have a definite and official name like a collection. Sometimes they appear as a node list or an exotic array. Normally you don't chose to use them they are given to you as a result of a query. They are array like objects having index like properties (0,1,2,3,...) and a length property as well. They are mostly iterable too but they don't have direct access to the Array.prototype.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/NodeList:

> Why is NodeList not an Array?
>
> NodeList are used very much like arrays and it's tempting to invoke
>   Array.prototype methods on them, however NodeList objects don't have
>   any of the familiar Array methods.
>
> JavaScript has an inheritance mechanism based on prototypes for both
>   built–in objects (like Arrays) and host objects (like NodeLists).
>   Array instances inherit array methods (such as forEach or map) because
>   their prototype chain looks like the following:
>
> myArray --> Array.prototype --> Object.prototype --> null (The
>   prototype chain of an object can be obtained by calling
>   Object.getPrototypeOf several times.)
>
> forEach, map and the likes are own properties of the Array.prototype
>   object.
>
> Unlike arrays, NodeList prototype chain looks like the following:
>
> myNodeList --> NodeList.prototype --> Object.prototype --> null
>
> NodeList.prototype contains the item method, but none of the
>   Array.prototype methods, so they cannot be used on NodeLists.

Answer (score 1):

**NodeLists** are very similar to **Array** collections of elements, often referred to as **“array-like”**, but with a subtle difference - you’re missing out on a lot of JavaScript functionality by keeping your collection as a NodeList, such as true Array iteration and Prototypal methods.

---

The NodeList interface provides the abstraction of an ordered collection of nodes, without defining or constraining how this collection is implemented.

---

NodeList to array

> var myArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(myList, 0);
>         undefined
>   myArray.constructor.toString();
>         "function Array() {
>             [native code]
>         }"